# I am not able to set the background image using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am not able to understand why in the background the image is not getting displayed.

```css
body{
 background-image: url('../Images/Chicken.jpeg');
 background: cyan;
}
```

The path of the image is right. whats the problem then? but the background color is getting being displayed.

Comment: Are you sure the image path is correct?

Answer (score 7):

Because you override an image with the color. If you want to use them both:

```
body{
    background-image: url('../Images/Chicken.jpeg');
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

or you can combine them in to one line:

```
body{
    background: cyan url('../Images/Chicken.jpeg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main {
  background-image: url('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-water-drop-on-dandelion-260nw-789676552.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center; 
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
</div>
```